# Problems deploying asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment

This the first time I'm deploying an asp.net application.

When I Build the deployment package i.e. right click on the project and select "Build Deployment Package" I get the following error:

> Error  1   Web deployment task failed.(Object of type 'dbFullSql' and path 'Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\JP\ASP\eTracking\test\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True' cannot be created.)
>
> Object of type 'dbFullSql' and path 'Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\JP\ASP\eTracking\test\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True' cannot be created.
>
> Cannot connect to the database 'C:\JP\ASP\eTracking\test\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf'.
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)       0   0   eTracking

Can anyone help with this.. I can't make sense out of it and can't seem to find a solution online.

> Ok Managed to solve the problem.
>
> In the properties window under the Package/Publish SQL untick the "Pull data and/or schema from an existing database" as well as the "Auto-generated Schema and Data" in the grid.

Comment: Ok Managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

worked: "Ok Managed to solve the problem. In the properties window under the Package/Publish SQL untick the "Pull data and/or schema from an existing database" as well as the "Auto-generated Schema and Data" in the grid.
"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error message is pretty straightforward - you are using a locally-attached database in your application.  This won't work with the packager.  You need to change the database access to a server database or you need to include the mdf file in your application.

Comment: I'm using a database on SQL Server 2008, I have not attached any other database to it, seems to be something that Visual Studio is doing.  I've gone into the webconfig file and removed: "AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf" but I still get the same error when building for deployment

Comment: Ok Managed to solve the problem.

In the properties window under the Package/Publish SQL untick the "Pull data and/or schema from an existing database" as well as the "Auto-generated Schema and Data" in the grid.